# Calculate (sha1) "pieces" when creating torrent file

Tags: php, hash, bittorrent

I'm almost done with my torrent server completely. All I have to do now is find out how .torrent files populate the "pieces" key for the info key.

I currently have this info in my torrent file, encoded in utf-8 format. The hash you see at the end is a has of the file's TITLE, not even close to the bit length I specified before the colon. The bit length for pieces was calculated using (filesize / piece length) * 20, and rounded using round():

```
d8:announce64:http://www.valevarkasystems.com:40/torrents/tracker/announce.php  

8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod6:lengthi71711042e4:name25:Executive Meeting480p.flv

12:piece lengthi128000e6:pieces11205:òOìcØq¬rkÑzÎõyjZee
```

How do I properly calculate a value for the "pieces" key at the end?

Everytime I try to open it in Transmission, it is read as corrupted.

Do I use fopen(), grab a piece of the file that is "piece length" and create a sha1 hash for each piece until I reach the end of the file?

Thanks,

Comment: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Info_Dictionary

Comment: @Marc Brown have you looked at the BEncode/BDecode php source maybe this would help, I can post both classes if you like

Comment: @MarcB I found/was referred that page so many times that I forgot I had three tabs open with it. I understand that they want me to hash each file piece, i.e. file_get_contents() where the maxlen is the size of my piece_length? I think that's all I have to do, but am not sure.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have seen the source code and I believe I have to do a while loop where I "sha1" each piece of the file that is the length of "piece length".

Comment: I'm actually making progress. Before I could ready my files as plain text. Now, after I created a while loop that "sha1" the parts of the file using file_get_contents I can no longer open the torrent file using a regular text editor (actually a good thing), but I still have a corrupt file some how... Any tips? Am I missing any thing? Do I need an info hash?

Comment: Now I'm happy. @LawrenceCherone . I just did what I stated in the past post, but I remove the function "utf_encode()" from around the data in the file and once I opened it using Transmission, it was no longer corrupt! Following the coding above, simply create a while statement that "file_get_contents()" where the offset is increased by "piece length * counter" and buffer is "piece length". Sha1() the returned string and concatenate the remaining sha1 file chunks. Remember to make sure the string count after "pieces" is divisible by 20. Now I just have to get my tracker to seed first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You read `piece size` number of bytes from the file, run each piece through SHA-1 independently. The resulting 20 byte SHA-1 digest is your piece, which is put as **binary** in the pieces string.

If you're using `fopen()` to read the data, make sure to open the file in binary mode (i.e. specify "b" as the mode). Otherwise your runtime may insert \r whenever it encounters a \n in the byte stream.

You should end up with `(filesize + piece_length - 1) / piece_length` number of pieces, which multiplied by 20 is the length of your `pieces` string.

It looks like you're only working with single file torrents. The multi-file torrent case is more complicated. You essentially have to imagine all the files in the torrent being concatenated to form the mapping from a piece to a file and offset.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just read about portability using the binary flag. But, I use "file_get_contents" anyway...